# How do I return empty XML (Type XmlElement) in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method which returns XML in C#( type: XmlElement). How do I return an Empty XML? Can't use string. Empty obviously.

Comment: see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703127/i-need-to-convert-an-xml-string-into-an-xmlelement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean, "empty"? Return null if you want to indicate nothing is being returned.

Otherwise, you'll need to return a minimal document, which consists of an empty element: `<element/>`.

Answer (score 0):

if there is an element like this in xml then while parsing in ie produces object required javascript error.

```
document.getElementById("city").value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

which can be stopped by adding if conditions