# I need to convert an XML string into an XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, type-conversion

I'm looking for the simplest way to convert a string containing valid XML into an `XmlElement` object in C#.

How can you turn this into an `XmlElement`?

```
<item><name>wrench</name></item>
```

Comment: Does the string have a single root element?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have a root element.

Comment: The way this is handled in .NET today is still frustratingly dumb. When the WSDL you dont control wants `XmlElement[]` after the svcutil generates your proxy, you are kind of forced weirdness.

Comment: Found another thread with some more solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936056/how-to-create-xelement-from-a-string

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use this:

```
private static XmlElement GetElement(string xml)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    return doc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Beware!!
If you need to add this element to another document first you need to Import it using `ImportNode`.

Comment: Wont this fail if there's no <?xml version bla bla> tag at the beginning? If he just has an xml fragment I don't think this will work..

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: IIRC LoadXml takes any well-formed XML fragment that contains exactly one XML element at the top level. `<?xml` at the beginning is not required.

Comment: To be clear, this works _only_ if the XML fragment does not contain more than a single element, so it can be treated as a root element. Otherwise, it throws an XmlException stating, "There are multiple root elements." For example, loading "<item/><item/>" this way would fail.

Answer (score 27):

Suppose you already had a XmlDocument with children nodes, And you need add more child element from string.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// Add some child nodes manipulation in earlier
// ..

// Add more child nodes to existing XmlDocument from xml string
string strXml = 
  @"<item><name>wrench</name></item>
    <item><name>screwdriver</name></item>";
XmlDocumentFragment xmlDocFragment = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
xmlDocFragment.InnerXml = strXml;
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("root").AppendChild(xmlDocFragment);
```

The Result:

```
<root>
  <item><name>this is earlier manipulation</name>
  <item><name>wrench</name></item>
  <item><name>screwdriver</name>
</root>
```

Comment: This seems to be the canonically correct way according to Ms docs. I dont know why it isnt the preferred solution

Answer (score 15):

Use [XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

(Or in case you're talking about XElement, use [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx):)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
XElement root = doc.Root;
```

Comment: He wanted the element, and for XElement he can just do XElement.Parse(xmlString), but you're giving him a document not element.

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: If you have a document, it's straightforward to get the root element, no?

Comment: Sure, was just saying your answer could be tailored to the posters question a little more in case it's not as easy for him as it is for us..

Answer (score 2):

You can use XmlDocument.LoadXml() to do this.

Here is a simple examle:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmlDoc.LoadXml("YOUR XML STRING");
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this snippet, Got the solution.

```
// Sample string in the XML format
String s = "<Result> No Records found !<Result/>";
// Create the instance of XmlDocument
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// Loads the XML from the string
doc.LoadXml(s);
// Returns the XMLElement of the loaded XML String
XmlElement xe = doc.DocumentElement;
// Print the xe
Console.out.println("Result :" + xe);
```

If any other better/ efficient way to implement the same, please let us know.

Thanks & Cheers