# how to create XElement from a string?

Tags: c#

Say I have a string like

```
string var = "This is a test";
```

Then I want to use this string to create an instance of XElement like:

```
XElement element =  XElement.Load(var);
```

Comment: Use vb.net -> Dim myX = <elementName>This is a test</elementName>… Done.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
XElement myX = new XElement("elementName", "This is a test");
```

This will be equivalent to the XML:

```
<elementName>This is a test</elementName>
```

Answer (score 52):

Use the XDocument.Parse method to parse the string into an XML Document.

```
var document = XDocument.Parse("<element>This is a test</element>");

var element = document.Root;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. I love your answer! It saved my time. I think it is also good to use `stringBuilder` and `string.Format()` to work with the string part. +1 for your answer! : )

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it just:

```
var el = new XElement("name", value);
```

? Elements need names, note.

Comment: I was gonna vote you up, but then I noticed that you have enough rep to bail out the mortgage vendors. Still... +1

Answer (score 5):

`XDocument.Parse(str).Root` returns `XElement`. `str` must be well-formed xml document.

If you want to construct xml you can: `XElement el = new XElement("Root");` (this means as if it was `<Root />`)

BTW your `string var = "This is a test";` is neither XML not valid XML tag name.